# In Java 9, why are package collisions treated a bit differently in some cases?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am experimenting with Java 9 and looking at the following scenarios:

**Experiment 1**

- module A
- module B
- both declare a non empty package named com.foo, but *do not export it*.
- both are required by a 3rd module C

Running a main from 'C' gives a runtime error:

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Package com.foo in both module B and module A*

**Experiment 2**

Same as before but this time both export com.foo.

Result of executing main from C:

*java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules B and A export package com.foo to module C*

**Experiment 3**

Same as 2, but this time I declared package com.foo in module C.

Now I get a compilation error:
*Error:(4, 1) java: module C reads package com.foo from both A and B*

Why aren't the first two cases not caught during compilation as well? Are there runtime properties I am not aware of that preclude resolution before executing the program?

Also, as far as error messages are concerned: in what way is the error message in experiment 2 better than the one given in experiment 1. It is not that if one of the modules does not export it that the end result will be any different. In other words, what was the consideration behind producing different error messages?

Comment: *"Why aren't the first two cases not caught during compilation as well?"* Because the compiler did not go through that *extended* analysis of packages not being directly used by module C. Why would it? Only #3 causes the compiler to even look at package `com.foo`. Now, if your #2 had tried to `import` a class from `com.foo`, it would probably fail compilation, since the compiler would have to figure out which module to get it from.

Comment: @Andreas, don't know about that - after all the same package is exported in both modules. I am practically giving it up to the compiler on a silver plate :). Even if it were a longer chain - considering the keywords - this is not a computationally complex problem. They are already creating the readability graph, so everything is out there.

Comment: So, they didn't do the extra (optional) work. If you think it's important, rather than asking *"why?"*, I'd suggest you file an enhancement request.

Comment: @Andreas, believe it or not, I am actually interested in the design considerations. I am hoping this question will draw the attention of Mark, Brian or Stuart - as with other questions I've asked on SO about API design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Experiment #2 and #3 are split package issues and should be errors at both compile-time and run-time. For #2 I can't tell from your post why you don't see a compilation error when compiling C. You should see an error with text like "module C reads package com.foo from both A and B".

Experiment #1 is probably A, B, and C on the application module path where they cannot all live in the same name space (same class loader) due to the overlapping packages. The error message you see has been improved a bit in recent builds.

Note that the experiments here have been discussed in many threads on [jigsaw-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/jigsaw-dev) and that might be better place to bring up questions and experiences, at least while JDK 9 is still in development.

Comment: Thanks Alan. If I understand correctly, I should be getting compilation errors in all cases. 
I will re-check and re-post this on the mailing list if needed. Now that I think of it, I am conducting the experiments an EA version of Intellij. It may be that they are missing something as well.

Comment: Experiment #1 will not result in a compilation error, the other two should. #1 will work at run-time when the modules are loaded into a child layer, just not the application module path.

Comment: So cool when you get an answer from @AlanBateman himself on SO!